# Use negative page number before the \mainmatter

Tags: page-numbering

I want to put negative number page before the main page of a book document class.

So, I will have something like page -4, -3, -2, -1, 0 (this is the first main page), 1, 2…

I can put on the top of the `document` environment `\setcounter{page}{-<number>}` but I have to know how many pages is before the `\mainmatter` to put it as a `<number>` variable. So how can I get this value?

Comment: You'd need two passes for that.

Comment: Are you aiming for a prize for the most unexpected and unusual page numbering look?

Comment: Yes Judobs, I know that. Mico, no I was just want to do that for a long time :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following example uses package `zref`, in especially `zref-abspage`, which provides a counter for the absolute page number. `\mainmatter` writes a reference `mainmatter` with property `abspage`, the absolute page number, into the `.aux` file. In the next run, the page number is set at the beginning in `\frontmatter`
to the negative number:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{zref-abspage}

\makeatletter
% Add label to \mainmatter for the absolute page number
\g@addto@macro\mainmatter{%
  \zref@labelbyprops{mainmatter}{abspage}%
}
\g@addto@macro\frontmatter{%
  % Overwrite \pagenumbering{roman} of the original \frontmatter
  \pagenumbering{arabic}%
  % Set the page number to the number of pages in the frontmatter
  % with reverted sign.
  \setcounter{page}{-\zref@extractdefault{mainmatter}{abspage}{0}}%
  % The label is already on page n + 1, the first page of the main matter.
  \stepcounter{page}%
  % Also page number 0 is available:
  \stepcounter{page}%
  % Ensure, that the first page is odd-numbered.
  \ifodd\value{page}%
  \else
    \addtocounter{page}{-1}%
  \fi
  \zref@refused{mainmatter}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Main chapter}
\end{document}
```

Result:

- Page -3: Contents
- Page -2: Empty page because of \cleardoublepage of the following `\chapter`
- Page -1: Chapter "Introduction"
- Page 0: Empty page because of \cleardobulepage of the following `\mainmatter`
- Page 1: Chapter "Main chapter", the first page in main matter

Comment: It’s good but I want to have the 0 page number on the page “Main chapter”, the first page in main matter. For this, have I to set `\setcounter{page}{-\zref@extractdefault{mainmatter}{abspage}{-1}}`?

Comment: @fauve However `0` is an even number, but chapters usually start with an odd page number on the right side.